# Find $m$ so that $(m+4\cdot41)(m^2+4^2\cdot41^2)$ is a square number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Question: Find the minimum positive odd interger $m$ so that $(m+4\cdot41)(m^2+4^2\cdot41^2)$ is a square number.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Rather multiply bracket i think itll get a hint of some number

Comment: Considering the case when $m=41k$ where $k$ is a positive odd integer will give you that $m=41\cdot 5=205$ is possible.

Comment: At this point an astute computer programmer would combine this with the result below, that m-5 is divisible by 8,and check all smaller possible cases. A less astute one would check every value from 1 to 204. Either way,it gets the answer but with no insight.

Comment: @user254665: No "astute computer programmer" is needed. This can be done very easily in a spreadsheet such as Microsoft Excel. I am often amazed that more people do not use this resource. And the question did not prohibit such answers.

Comment: @RoryDaulton. I was thinking of a friend,who is a top-notch programmer. If you tell him that an answer lies in a known bounded set  his response will be, "Compute it then."  I think I'll try to get him to compute Ramsey numbers :)

Comment: I did a very quick spreadsheet, and the answer is $m=205$ and the expression equal to $5043^2$. That method may or may not be acceptable in your case. Let me know if you need details on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks folks. This question was given to high school students as a challenge question. I also heard that the source of this problem may be some Math Olympiad. So I would think that there must be some more way to further narrow down the range without having to examine all 5,10,15,...,200,205.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Since $m$ is an odd positive integer, so we must have
$$(m+4\cdot 41)(m^2+4^2\cdot 41^2)\equiv 1 \pmod 8$$
$$m^3+4^3\cdot 41^3 + m\cdot 4\cdot 41(m+4\cdot 41) \equiv 1 \pmod 8$$

Comment: So $m\equiv 5 \pmod 8$ because for odd $m$ we have, (mod $8$) $m^2\equiv 1$ and $m^3\equiv m^2.m\equiv m.$